# Как получить имя или IP сетевого адаптера (интерфейса), используемого для доступа в Интернет С#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, сеть

Заголовок выражает суть вопроса.

Comment: Видимо надо покурить вот [это](http://stackoverflow.com/a/515607)

Answer (score 2):

Тут не все так просто: получить список интерфейсов не сложно, а вот определить, какой из них смотрит наружу (причем не в локальную сеть, например, а именно в Internet) - придется самому. Какие могут быть критерии - это не loopback-интерфейс, есть gateway и т.п.

Для начала попробуйте так:

```
foreach ( NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces() )
            {
                if ( ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up && ni.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback )
                {
                    // ваш выход
                }
            }
```

Comment: Изначально я предполагал, что для доступа в Интернет используется интерфейс с самой малой метрикой среди всех. В большинстве случаев это так, но всё же исключения встречаются не так редко.

Comment: @SNMetamorph, мне кажется, это действительно не самое удачное решение - а если при расстановке приоритетов будет использоваться такая характеристика как скорость соединения? Это может все испортить.

Comment: @SNMetamorph, если для Вас это не критично - можете отправить Ping чз каждый найденный интерфейс. С учетом вышеупомянутых факторов как "отсеивающих" точно неподходящие интерфейсы.